# How can GraphQL React useMutation be combined using try catch or another way?

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I could not think of how to rewrite through try catch that would unite in one
or how to make it more compact

```
  const [addShopTraffic, { error: errorAddShopTraffic, data: addShopTrafficData }] = useMutation(CREATE_SHOP_TRAFFIC_MUTATION);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (getProp(errorEditShopTraffic, "message")) {
      console.log(getProp(errorEditShopTraffic, "message"));
    }
  }, [errorEditShopTraffic]);
```

Comment: Personally, I wrote a custom hook around my queries where errors are managed in a generic way

Comment: If you want to run an effect if the mutation errors you can simply use `addShopTraffic(...).catch(console.log)`. If you want to do other stuff you are probably not using the hook correctly. The hook is designed for displaying something in the render function, when an error happens.